# What's the difference between ListView and FlatList?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

According to Facebook's documentation,

> ListView - A core component designed for efficient display of
> vertically scrolling lists of changing data.
>
> FlatList - A performant interface for rendering simple, flat lists.

It seems both are efficient. What should we consider when choosing one from the other?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[FlatList](https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6) - More performant compared to ListView. ListView rendering can get slow once the number of items grows larger. FlatList significantly improves memory usage and efficiency (especially for large or complex lists) while also significantly simplifying the props — no more dataSource necessary!

**Features**
Flatlist is packed with new components full of features to handle the majority of use cases out of the box:

- Scroll loading (onEndReached).
- Pull to refresh (onRefresh / refreshing).
- Configurable viewability (VPV) callbacks (onViewableItemsChanged / viewabilityConfig).
- Horizontal mode (horizontal).
- Intelligent item and section separators.
- Multi-column support (numColumns)
- scrollToEnd, scrollToIndex, and scrollToItem
- Better Flow typing.

<strike>FlatList is still missing some features, like sticky headers, but it's evolving fast. *ListView is going to get [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html).*</strike>

ListView is **[deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html)** now and Sticky Headers in Flat list working now

**Better options out there**

I was getting performance issues while rendering 5000+ items in flat-list. Looked for other alternatives and found [recyclerlistview](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview) - High performance list-view for React Native and web. Much better scrollTo performance and better rendering optimisations compared to flat-list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how do you know ListView is going to be deprecated?

Comment: @C.Lee the official blog post on the React Native blog mentions this -> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views.html