# React native slow loading components

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to load 1051 components, but it takes a lot, also the manipulation of this data.

```
this.state = {
    data: valori,
 }
```

In data are loaded all components. Than

```
  let newElements = this.state.data.map( (data, index) => {
      return (
        <Display enable={data.visible}>
        <View key={data.key} pass_in_data={data}>
          <Text style={[styles.categoria, {backgroundColor: colori[data.category]}]}>{data.category}</Text>
          <View style={styles.inlineBlock}>
          <Text style={styles.titoloPubblicazione} >{data.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.dataPubblicazione}>{data.data}</Text>
          </View>
     </View>
   </Display>
      )
  });
```

in return there is;

```
<ScrollView>
    {newElements}
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch to Flatlist

Heavy performance compared to scroll View and list view.
ScrollView renders everything at once , but flat list has techniques to lazy render items making blazing fast.

[What's the difference between ListView and FlatList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44510236/whats-the-difference-between-listview-and-flatlist/44512309#44512309)

Minimal Example:

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

Refer [Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

Comment: Thanks, Just a question, than Can I update a component?

Comment: @VincenzoCarlino yes u can update items in the list by updating the data

Comment: Yes but when I do it it takes a lot of time. I will post the code down as an answer